# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal' to type 'CustomPrincipal'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I get this error when deploying my web site on server while locally it works well. The error occurs in CusomAuthorizeAttribute when casting:

```
CustomPrincipal user = (CumtomPrincipal)httpContext.User;
```

I thought about diversity in versions of .Net frameworks on my local and server, but they both target the same 4.5 version. My CustomPrincipal Implements IPrincipal interface, as well as httpContext.User.

I have found this question asked a lot of times but there is no answer to it.

Comment: Can you give more information e.g. where you use this line of code?

Comment: This code is from AuthorizeCore method of CustomAuthorizeAttribute.